# Remote server returns error page after sending credentials

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I'm trying to create simple webpage that allows me to check current schedule from information system. IS is written in ASP.NET and using library to generate random name values for inputs. Also it uses one-time log in token.

I wrote this script to log in and fetch current schedule.

```
<?php
function curl($url, $post=false,$cookie = 'cookie.txt'){

$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);



    if($cookie){

        $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36";
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

    }

    if($post){
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }

     return  curl_exec ($ch);
}


// require simple html dom library to work with html later
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

// login page uri
$login_page = "http://bakalari.sosklobouky.cz:82/login.aspx";

// fetch login page
$ch = curl($login_page ,false);
// create simple html dom to read hidden inputs, etc.
$html = str_get_html($ch);

// add all hidden inputs into string
$hidden_inputs = '';
foreach ($html->find('input[type=hidden]') as $element) {
    $hidden_inputs .= '&'.$element->name.'='.$element->value;
}

// fetch actual name atributes of username and password form
$username_name = $html->find('input[tabindex=1]', 0)->name;
$password_name = $html->find('input[tabindex=2]', 0)->name;

// credentials
$username = "9703042329z";
$password = "somepass";

// post data - credentials + hidden inputs
$postdata = $username_name . '=' . $username . '&' . $password_name . '=' . $password . $hidden_inputs;

// send request to login page with credentials
$ch = curl($login_page ,$postdata);

// print result
echo $ch;

// try to fetch page that is available after login
$ch = curl('http://bakalari.sosklobouky.cz:82/uvod.aspx',false);

// print return
echo $ch;
?>
```

But remote server returns error of application. Do you have any ideas? Maybe I'm sending postdata badly. I'm not sure, because I'm writing script like this one for first time.

Comment: If you're getting errors, use [curl_error()](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to check what went wrong

Comment: At one point you're calling your curl handle `$ch`, and at another point you're calling the response `$ch`. So my first suggestion is to make sure that you understand the difference and pick a different name for the response.

Comment: @Alon: it returns something like internal server error - I can't see the errror because of secutiry.

pguardiario: I'm sure the problem is somewhere else. But I tried to rename variables. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Close the curl handle, otherwise it will not save cookie for every call(It will only when the program ends).

```
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

From the log and the latest conversation, here is the **UPDATE**

You are trying to POST a large number of data(currently 1155 bytes). And through normal post, you can not pass more than 1024 bytes data. And hence you are getting `100 Continue` response from the site.

So, convert your post into `multipart/form-data` and you'll get passed. Here is how you can do it.

Make an array with all your post values.

```
$post_data = array(

  'name' => 'some name',
  'pass' => 'some pass',
  'hidden-1' => 'some hidden-1',  // you may need to do urlencode() here, I am not sure
  'others-1' => 'some others 1'
   /// and so on

);
```

Then post the array directly into the curl post like below:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Comment: Didn't help, I double-checked the cookie.txt and there were some cookies. The server returned me ASP.NET_SessionId (which is the only cookie I need). But after the server returns error (something like 500, but it's not Apache - because of APS.NET) except for the dashboard page after logging. I have the sessionID so I'm probably logged in... But it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JiriTravnicek you need to parse hidden params like `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTARGUMENT` from the page and provide through the POST parameter.

Comment: I already did - check the code bellow `// add all hidden inputs into string` comment,

Comment: Yes, in deed. You used html parser so got confused. Anyway, 1) do urlencode on `$element->value` 2) use empty('') for `CURLOPT_ENCODING` 3) enable verbose mode `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and show us the debug print(can be on log, or screen based on your setting).

Comment: Ok, now it returns login form again. Why? I'm sending credentials and all hidden inputs. What more it can want?

Comment: First try setting `true` for curl option `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` By this time I am updating my answer describing why, and what else you can do.

Comment: My code update - http://pastebin.com/3w8fQiiB also I got different verbose output - http://pastebin.com/mXuSQbc8. Now I'm getting 500 again.

Comment: Also I tried to don't use `urlencode()` now. And It returned 100 and 200 - http://pastebin.com/iNg9kvAF

Comment: Did you use the option `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR`? Your problem is interesting.

Comment: Yes, I did. After I pasted this option into my code it didn't return anything. Just blank page. Should it return error or something? It sounds like "stop on error", doesn't it?

Comment: Do you have any other ideas, plase?